# Drivers Issues in DELL-Inspiron-3543

Tags: 18.04

I installed " Broadcom Limited  BCM43142 802.11b/g/n " in my dell laptop 
Inspiron -3543 , all things are work properly but it don't shows me some available WiFi network which i can able to see in Mobile device ,

please give me solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think there would be a solution?

BCM43142 is for 2.4GHz networks only.
Your phone probably supports 5GHz networks as well.

That's the difference.

Comment: yes it is but when i turn on my leptop with windows OS it shows me all wifi network....